# Pass Dictionary<int, string> from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Model:

```
public string FreeText { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, string> SearchValues { get; set; }
public List<DropDownModel> DropDowns { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSearchResults", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FreeText, new { @class = "form-control mb-3", @placeholder = "Search..." })

    foreach (var dropDown in Model.DropDowns)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchValues[dropDown.DataFieldId], dropDown.ListItems, dropDown.OptionLabel, new { @class = "form-control mb-3" });
    }

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
}
```

The FreeText input field is being passed perfectly fine. But even though the dropdown for the SearchValues field is displayed correctly on the page, it is returned as empty (Count = 0) in the controller. Why is this, can I pass a dictionary to the controller?

Comment: You're trying to save the dropdown FieldId to int and Dropdown Value to string is that correct?

Comment: @JerdineSabio Yes, that's 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a mapper or changing how model properties are bound, the easiest way to do this is create a class for your SearchValues.

1. Create SearchValue class

```
public class SearchValue{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string value {get;set;}
}
```

2. Use that as a List in your model

```
public string FreeText { get; set; }
// replace dictionary
public List<SearchValue> SearchValues { get; set; }
public List<DropDownModel> DropDowns { get; set; }
```

3. Then use the view below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSearchResults", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FreeText, new { @class = "form-control mb-3", @placeholder = "Search..." })

    @{
        int counter = 0;
    }
    foreach (var dropDown in Model.DropDowns)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="SearchValues[@counter].Id" value="@dropdown.DataFieldId">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchValues[counter].Value, dropDown.ListItems, dropDown.OptionLabel, new { @class = "form-control mb-3" });
        @counter++;
    }

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to retain the Dictionary format by changing the kvp from `<int, string>` to `<string, string>`. Apparently the model binder only accepts the key in string format.